# how to use same form code for add and update in node Js?

Tags: node.js

I need the Same Function to save and update the data in Below code,

below I attache my code snippet.

```
controller.save = (req, res) => {    const data = req.body; req.getConnection((err, connection) => {        const query = connection.query('INSERT INTO client set ?', data, (err, client) => {
            res.redirect('/');       })    })};//this is insert code



controller.update = (req, res) => {    const { id } = req.params;
    const newData = req.body;    req.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        connection.query('update client set? where id =?', [newData, id], (err, rows) => {   res.redirect('/');   });   }); }; //this is update code
```

please clarify my doubts, save and update the same form using node js

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the data you want to insert/update exists in database and then decide which query to perform, insert or update.

For better performance you need to extract those features/columns which makes your record unique.